# How to create NuGet package from class library projects and precompiled views?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, nuget

I'm using MVC 5 on my Visual Studio 2017. My VS solution currently looks like this

- Solution

  - MVC App
  - Components (class library)
  - Custom view engine (class library)

Now I have created models in Components library. 
These models are used in MVC app views. 
I have configured MVC App to precompile views during publishing with "Merge all outputs to a single assembly" and marked "Treat as library component".

Components project is referenced to MVC app (to use it in views). Custom view engine is also referenced to MVC app (to mark (in AssemblyInfo) that this library contains custom views).

When I publish MVC app it compile all views to a single library.

But I want to create NuGet package from Components project and the views. How can I do it? Is there any option to automate this?

Comment: are you using i.e. Azure DevOps? you can create a build that creates a nuget package every time you create a pull request

Comment: @vhr no I'm not using Azure DevOps

Comment: you can do it using Visual Studio like here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-and-publish-a-nuget-package-using-visual-studio-net-standard/

Comment: not sure where you want to use it but you can skip publishing to nuget and use/reference the package you created directly

Comment: I'm using Publishing tool only to precompile views. Is there any other possibilities without installing third party library?

Answer (score 0):

While NuGet has functionality to pack a project, it uses the compiler output, not the publisher output, and automatically adds all MSBuild `Content` types, which might not be desired in your case (I have no idea how precompiled views work).

Anyway, you can always create a [`.nuspec` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/reference/nuspec) and have it pack the output of the publish command. At the end of the docs page there are [several complete examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/reference/nuspec#example-nuspec-files) of `nuspec` files.

It's been a long time since I worked on an ASP.NET project, but my memory is that MVC only automatically detects MVC controllers and razor views from the "main" assembly. If you have additional controllers or views in a project reference or a nuget package, you may need to register them.